# Div's and elements moving and overlapping on resizing of html page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Whack a Head</title>
  <link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script>
    var objDiv = document.getElementById("applet");
    objDiv.scrollTop = 40;

</script>
  </head>
  
<body background="images/newbackground.png" style="background-size:cover;">
<script>
var w=window.innerWidth
|| document.documentElement.clientWidth
|| document.body.clientWidth;

var h=window.innerHeight
|| document.documentElement.clientHeight
|| document.body.clientHeight;

x=document.getElementById(“demo”);
x.innerHTML=“Browser inner window width: ” + w + “, height: ” + h + “.”
</script>
<div align="center"  style="margin-top:10px;position:absolute;">
<img src="images/newheaderimage1.png" alt=""style="height:auto;max-width:100%;min-width:50%;margin-top:-10px;">

<div align="center"  style="">
<img src="images/whack.png" alt=""style="width:480px;height:280px;z-index:1;margin-top:-920px;">
</div>

<div id="1" align="center"style="width:100%;height:70%;margin-top:-785px;">
<div align="center" style="display: box;flex-align: center;flex-pack: center;position:relative;overflow-y: hidden; height: 437px; overflow-x: hidden; width:775px;margin-top:1%;" id="applet">

    <iframe style="margin-top:-171px;border-right:0px;border-color:black;border-left:0px; margin-left:-10px;margin-bottom:-50px;" allowtransparency="false" width="800" height="720"  bgcolor=#F11111 src="https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/embed/117167238/?autostart=true&bg=#4c4c4c" allowfullscreen>
 </iframe>
 </div> 
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have designed an html page with some images and an iframe, i want my header image to scale and when i make height suto for my header image then on window resize all the other content below it starts to move up and overlap each other ? Please help here is my current code and screen shot of whats happening and what i want to achive ?

Below you coud find my complete html code please help??[number 1 image describes This is what i want to achive even on window resize that the elements dont move and heder image scale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbXAS.jpg)

This is whats happeneing? [Number 2 iage describes what the problem is on window resize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8qG3.jpg)

Comment: Please anyone help ?

Comment: Your snippet is broken - please create a fiddle, or a pen on https://codepen.io/ and add it to your question. Thanks!

Comment: Could you clarify what you want your header to scale to? Can you cut down your HTML until absolutely all that's left is the problem? The facebook and other social buttons are only cluttering up the issue. You'll only get help once its easy to help you.

Comment: @pawel: here is the working link :-

whacahead.wpengine.com

here you would see on windows resize the image streches what i want is the image size should scale and should not strech and also the social media icons below move around i want them to be fixed ?

Comment: @Tankor: here is the working link :- whacahead.wpengine.com here you would see on windows resize the image streches what i want is the image size should scale and should not strech and also the social media icons below move around i want them to be fixed ? please kindly help?

Comment: here is the working link :- whacahead.wpengine.com here you would see on windows resize the image streches what i want is the image size should scale and should not strech and also the social media icons below move around i want them to be fixed ? Please kindly help ??

Comment: @danny Thanks for the working link. Now can you reduce the HTML to the dozen lines or so it would take so that we can see clearly what the problem is? Also, what's the difference between scaling and stretching.

Comment: @Tankor: I have cut short the html code so whats happening is i have a fluid header image named new header image 1 and that is scaling on windows resize not streching but properly scaling but the problem is when i resize my window all the elements below it comes on top of it and overlaps each other ?

Comment: Thanks that clears it up a bit. Hope you find some help, I'm stumped.

Comment: @Tankor: Thanks a  lot, please write if you could find any solution, thanks

Comment: Anyone please help ?